# Laravel pagination-sm pagination-lg class not working together for different breakpoint

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

This is what I'm trying but only `pagination-sm` class is working on all breakpoint

```php
<ul class="pagination mb-0 pagination-sm pagination-lg" role="navigation">
    <li class="page-item"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: pagination-sm is not a media query specific CSS. It means that the pagination items must be shown small in all views.If you need different styles for small and large devices, you will need to add some custom media query CSS to do so

Comment: Can you suggest me how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pagination-sm` is not a media query specific CSS. It means that the pagination items must be shown small in all views.If you need different styles for small and large devices, you will need to add some custom media query CSS to do so.

```css
.pagination .page-link {
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .pagination .page-link {
    padding: .5rem .75rem;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .pagination .page-link {
    padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example" class="mt-4">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with SASS** - better solution without JS but SASS (add this code after importing all bootstrap components):

```
@include media-breakpoint-between(xs,md) {
  .pagination {
    @include pagination-size($pagination-padding-y-sm, $pagination-padding-x-sm, $font-size-sm, $pagination-border-radius-sm);
  }
}
```

**Solution with JavaScript** - At least for the existing sm-variant you could do something like that:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const helper = document.getElementById('extendedPaginationHelper');
    const pagination = document.getElementById('extendedPagination');
    
    let timeout = false;
    let toggleClass;

    (toggleClass = function() {
        if (window.getComputedStyle(helper).display == 'none') {
            pagination.classList.remove('pagination-sm');
        } else {
            pagination.classList.add('pagination-sm');
        }
    })();
    
    addEventListener('resize', (event) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(toggleClass, 100);
    });
});
</script>

<div class="d-md-none" id="extendedPaginationHelper"></div>
<ul class="pagination" id="extendedPagination">
    <!-- ... pagination code -->
</ul>
```